# Linear Algebra, Finding Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the matrix of a given linear operator in given new bases:
a) L=< e<sub>1</sub>, e<sub>2</sub>, e<sub>3</sub>>, M=< ge<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>>

f(e<sub>1</sub>)=g<sub>1</sub>-2g<sub>2</sub>, f(e<sub>2</sub>)=g<sub>1</sub>+g<sub>2</sub>, f(e<sub>3</sub>)=2g<sub>1</sub>+3g<sub>2</sub>

e ̃<sub>1</sub>=2e<sub>1</sub>−e<sub>3</sub>, e ̃<sub>2</sub>=e<sub>2</sub>+e<sub>3</sub>, e ̃<sub>3</sub>=e<sub>1</sub>−e<sub>2</sub>

g ̃<sub>1</sub>=g<sub>1</sub>+2g<sub>2</sub>, g ̃<sub>2</sub>=2g<sub>1</sub>-g<sub>2</sub>

So far I have this, what are the next steps?

f(e ̃<sub>1</sub>) = 2f(e<sub>1</sub>)-f(e<sub>3</sub>) = 2(g<sub>1</sub>-2g<sub>2</sub>)-(2g<sub>1</sub>+3g<sub>2</sub>) = -7g<sub>2</sub>

f(e ̃<sub>2</sub>) = f(e<sub>2</sub>)+f(e<sub>3</sub>) = g<sub>1</sub>+g<sub>2</sub>+2g<sub>1</sub>+3g<sub>2</sub> = 3g<sub>1</sub> + 4g<sub>2</sub>

f(e ̃<sub>3</sub>) = f(e<sub>1</sub>)-f(e<sub>2</sub>) = g<sub>1</sub>-2g<sub>2</sub>-g<sub>1</sub>-g<sub>2</sub> = -3g<sub>2</sub>

Comment: Is $ge_1$ in the first line meant to be $g_1$?

Answer (score 0):

Recall the change of basis formula for a linear transformation: If $A=\operatorname{Mat}_{L,M}(f)$ is the matrix of a linear transformation $f$ with respect to the bases $L$ and $M$, and $P$ and $Q$ map from $L$ to $\tilde L$ and $M$ to $\tilde M$, respectively, then the matrix of $f$ with respect to $\tilde L$ and $\tilde M$ is $\operatorname{Mat}_{\tilde L,\tilde M}(f)=QAP^{-1}$. These matrices are easy to find if you remember that the columns of a matrix that represents a linear transformation are the images of the basis vectors.

In this problem, we’re given the operation of $f$ on the $L$ and $M$ bases, so we can write down $\operatorname{Mat}_{L,M}(f)$ directly: $$\operatorname{Mat}_{L,M}(f)=\pmatrix{1 & 1 & 2 \\ -2 & 1 & 3}.$$ Similarly, we can write down the matrices for the $\tilde L\to L$ and $\tilde M\to M$ mappings directly from the given information. I’ll leave that and the inversion and multiplications to find $\operatorname{Mat}_{\tilde L,\tilde M}(f)$ to you.